# On click lightning exp shows Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, winter19

I am using Lightning Experience, I created an App and I set Page D to be my first page when I access the App, there I have a link to Page E. If I log out and access SF again and click on App Launcher and click on my App, it loads the page D, but if I click on the link that I have in Page D that redirects to Page E, I got this error message in console:

Uncaught (in promise)

```
YB {component: "laf:appLayoutHost$controller$handlePageReferenceTransaction"....
```

> "Action failed: laf:appLayoutHost$controller$handlePageReferenceTransaction [[LAF:AppLayoutHost:extractPageLevelReference] Expected app-level reference but got {"type":"standard__directCmpReference","attributes":{"name":"one:alohaPage","attributes":{"address":"https://xxx-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/apex/Page_E"}},"state":{}}]"

If I click on the Tab that I called Page AD or refresh the page, the issue goes away. However, if I go to App Launcher again, then click on another App, then click back on App Launcher and click on my app again and click on the link to page E, I got the error again.

Page D and Page E are a simple visual force page, nothing fancy because was created for this test. The link is an anchor HTML tag.

```
<apex:page controller="Page_D_Controller" sidebar="false" >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>VSF Page D - Final Page</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <br />
  <a href="/apex/Page_E">Go to Page E</a>
</apex:page>
```

I recorded it.

http://nimb.ws/tkpfYi

This happen for my actual app and I created this app just o validate if this is a general error.

Do you have any idea on how I can avoid/fix this error?

Comment: Please do share the code as well, that would be a really great help to identify the issue.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened a case with Salesforce and they have identified that was a bug. They have fixed and it will be released on Spring 19.